# Ошибка при открытии проекта в Android Studio

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio

Использую Andoid Studio 2.1.2, после открытия готового проекта выходит ошибка:

> Failed to sync Gradle project.
>   Error: Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy setting in Gradle.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как решить проблему?

Comment: у вас подключен интернет?

Comment: при открыти**И** проекта

Comment: Да проект подключен к интернету

Comment: Пишите ошибки текстом, а не скриншотами. Пользователям с аналогичной ошибкой для решения такой-же проблемы будет трудно найти ее по скриншоту с помощью поиска.

Answer (score 2):

Либо не настроен Прокси ! (О чём и сказано в сообщении)
Либо виноваты санкции (сайт не принимает коннект от крымских)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, проблема оказалось совсем в другом. Я не правильно открывал проект и решил следующим образом импортировал проект с нуля

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

File > Settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > HTTP Proxy [Under IDE Settings] Enable following option Auto-detect proxy settings

Comment: Владимир Seos-Lab ошибка убралась, но теперь появилась следующая ошибка:

Error (19, 0)

Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Possible causes:


The project 'MuNs' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Open Gradle wrapper file


The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply Gradle plugin

Comment: Покажите app.gradle и build.gradle